# mongodump with date in query parameter using shell script

Tags: bash, mongodb, mongodump

I am trying to take mongodump of a collections of last 24 hours using bash  but getting errors as i am unable to use custom date in query parameter of mongodump statement.

```
timeInMs=$(expr "$(date +'%s%3N')" - 86400000)

mongodump -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname -c collection --query '{startTime:{$gte:new Date(${timeInMs})}}'
```

**timeInMs** is as expected (time in ms 24 hrs ago) but problem is getting query right. Lots of hit & trial used but no success yet. Have used following :

'{startTime:{$gte:{"$date":"${timeInMs}"}}}'

"{startTime:{$gte:new Date\"(${timeInMs})\"}}"

'{startTime:{$gte:new Date("${timeInMs}")}}'

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your quotes properly:

```
timeInMs=$(expr "$(date +'%s%3N')" - 86400000)
mongodump -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname -c collection --query '{startTime:{$gte:new Date('"$timeInMs"')}}'
```

For better readability:

```
mongodump -u user \
-p password \
--authenticationDatabase admin \
--db dbname -c collection --query  '{startTime:{$gte:new Date('"$timeInMs"')}}'
```

Comment: new Date takes number as parameter in case of ms , but these quotes result in string conversion.

Comment: I assumed you have timeInMs set, if you do that's what Mongod dump will get: `mongodump -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname -c collection --query {startTime:{$gte:new Date(1424940476866)}}`